# Как в творительном падеже «2017 год»?

Tags: падежи

В творительном падеже «2017 год» как звучит? Две тысячи семнадцатым годом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Творительный падеж: (любуюсь *чем?*) две тысячи семнадцатым годом.

У порядкового числительного 2017 «две тысячи» является неизменяемой частью, которая одинаково пишется во всех падежах, склоняется только «семнадцать».